# HTTP: 403 with Phileo app

Tags: python, django

I'm writing my first app in Django 1.8 and I'd like to use Phileo. I followed the [instructions](http://phileo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) to the letter but the console returns this when liking a model though the widget:

```
"POST /likes/like/12:1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274 (forbidden)
```

Is this an authentication or a url issue? I tried adding `csrf_exempt` to my blog view but get the same result.

I also tried running it without Eldarion but then i get a blank page and:

```
"GET /likes/like/12:2/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0  (method not allowed)
```

Any hints are really appreciated!

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'phileo',
    'crispy_forms',
    'location_field',
    'imagekit',
)

PHILEO_LIKABLE_MODELS = {
    'app.Post': {},
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'phileo.auth_backends.CanLikeBackend',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^likes/', include('phileo.urls')),
    url(r'^post/(?P<post_id>\d+)/post.html$', 'app.views.post', name='post'),
...
)
```

in my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="{% static 'app/eldarion/js/eldarion-ajax.min.js %}"></script>

{% load phileo_tags %}
{% phileo_widget user post %}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting are HTTP codes. Both 403 and 405 are under the category of bad request.

> Error code 403: Forbidden - The server understood the request, but is
>   refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request
>   SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the
>   server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled,
>   it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the
>   server does not wish to make this information available to the client,
>   the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.
>
> Error code 405: Method not allowed - The method specified in the
>   Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the
>   Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a
>   list of valid methods for the requested resource.

[source](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Unfortunately, I can't really help you with your code because you haven't posted it. Typically, a 403 means a permission issue. A 405 typically means what you requested was bad. You can try to contact your ISP.

Comment: Thank you. This is running on localhost. Maybe the app just doesn't work with Django 1.8.